# Log plots in matplotlib is creating two lines

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I was wondering why my loglog plots are creating two lines when it's just the orange one I want and why the labels won't show? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1 = [(3, 5034), (2, 4596), (4, 1469), (5, 1209), (6, 540), (7, 380), (8, 196), (9, 136), (10, 71), (11, 47), (12, 39), (13, 20), (14, 16), (15, 12), (16, 6), (18, 5), (17, 2), (19, 2), (22, 2), (1, 1), (24, 1), (20, 1)]
plt.loglog(data1, basex=2, basey=2, label='N1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `tp`? Maybe you meant `data1`?

Comment: Oops, yes, it's data1.

Comment: Because you passed two data sets in. If you want the first element of the tulle plotted against the second split them into two lists.  As for the label that is for legends

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!